# Integral points on elliptic curves of the form $y^2=x^3+px$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves

As the title says. Can we determine all the integral points on elliptic curves of the form

$$y^2=x^3+px$$

for a prime $p$? If yes, can someone explain me how? A good reference would also be sufficient.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is completely worked out in Walsh's paper:

- P. G. Walsh, [Integer Solutions to the Equation $y^2=x(x^2\pm p^k)$](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.rmjm/1214947612) (2008)

In particular, for your elliptic curve $y^2=x^3+px$, there are at most 2 primitive integer solutions if $p>3$, and 4 if $p=3$.

As for imprimitive solutions in this case ($k=1$, $d=p$), the proof of theorem 4 indicates that such a solution would be a counterexample to the Ankeny-Artin-Chowla conjecture.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But it seems that there is no explanation how to determine the imprimitive solutions of $k=1$. In section $7$ on page 1299 he explain how to compute imprimitive solutions only for $k>3$. Does that mean that there are no imprimitive solutions for $k\leq 3$?

Comment: @Marc Look at the last paragraph of page 1297 and the first one of 1298. I think the conclusion is that there is no solution if and only if the Ankeny-Artin-Chowla conjecture is true, so it is an open problem (but most likely true).